# calculate percentage change between first and last row of each column in a matrix

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, percentage

I would like to find a way to calculate the percentage change in the first and last row of each column in the matrix below.  I have tried playing around with for loops and tail(df[i],1)/head(df[i],1) -1 but I can't seem to get it right.

Apologize for the dummy question, but I have gotten pretty frustrated here..

```
 df=matrix(c(3,9,3,4,3,9,3,5,3,8,8,8),4,3)
 df
 ### return list/vector of 3 elements where values are 4/3 -1, 5/3 -1, and 8/3 -1 ....the returns of the last over first
```

Comment: `(df[nrow(df),] - df[1,]) / df[1,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `apply`:

```
> df <- matrix(c(3,9,3,4,3,9,3,5,3,8,8,8),4,3)
> df
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    3    3
[2,]    9    9    8
[3,]    3    3    8
[4,]    4    5    8
> apply(df, 2, function(col) (col[nrow(df)]/col[1]) - 1)
[1] 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.6666667
```

Comment: thank you to both - also just discovered matrix.head & matrix.tail right after i installed the latest version of Rstudio.  autocompletes are much better and the popups showed me these two commands I didn't know existed.